# Why does TikZ with pgfplots trim my graph like this?

Tags: pgfplots

### Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
     [   
         xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
         xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
         domain=-2:2,
         restrict y to domain=-4:4,
         grid=both,
         clip=true,
         axis lines=middle,
         enlarge y limits={rel=0.1},
         enlarge x limits={rel=0.1}
     ]
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, smooth] {x}   node [pos=1, above] {$x$};
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, smooth] {x^3} node [pos=1, above] {$x^3$};
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, smooth] {x^5} node [pos=1, above] {$x^5$};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Output

[image: plot picture]

### Questions

1. Why is the plot of `x^5` trimmed so much on the y axis? I'd like all functions to be visible from -4 to +4 on y.
2. Is the way I add labels to my functions fine? Actually, is there a 'preferred way' to do it?
3. Finally, can I somehow set the grid so that like on the x axis, there's a gridline for each integer? (Right now, I only see horizontal lines at -4, -2, +2, +4. Sorry, I don't know how to phrase this better, I am not a native English speaker; hope you understand)

Thanks in advance for your help, which will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For 2., what do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry, 'better' really wasn't an accurate description. I was trying to ask if this would be a 'preferred' way to put **function** labels. I am referring to those, above the curves of my functions. (I have also updated my question, it's now clearer, I hope)

Comment: Right, I see. I think that's a perfectly fine way of doing it. (`pos=1` is unnecessary by the way.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. May I ask what the use of that would be then? I have seen it somewhere, that's why I added it.

Comment: The `pos` key is used if you want to place a node at an arbitrary position along the path. `pos=0` is at the start of a path, `pos=0.5` is halfway, `pos=1` is at the end. But when you place a `node` at the end of a command like in your case, `pos=1` is the default, hence not needed.

Comment: Basically, the problem in 1. is that `pgfplots` uses just 25 samples for a plot by default, in combination with `restrict y to domain`. With `domain=-2:2`, the function is calculated at x=-2, x=-1.833, x=1.667, etc. (The step is 4/24=1/6.) So you get a point at x=1.667, giving y=2.16, and the next at x=1.333, giving y=4.21. But because of `restrict y to domain=-4:4`, all y-values above 4 are replaced by `nan`, and the plot thus ends at the point (1.6667, 2.16). A higher number of samples will help, see my comment on Zarko's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Basically, the problem is that `pgfplots` uses just 25 samples for a plot by default, in combination with `restrict y to domain`. With `domain=-2:2`, the function is calculated at x=-2, x=-1.833, x=1.667, etc. (The step is 4/24=1/6.) So you get a point at x=1.667, giving y=2.16, and the next at x=1.333, giving y=4.21. But because of `restrict y to domain=-4:4`, all y-values above 4 are replaced by nan, and the plot thus ends at the point (1.6667, 2.16). A higher number of samples can help with that.
2. I think this is a perfectly fine way of doing it.

   But consider one thing: If you remove `enlarge y limits={rel=0.1}`, the nodes with the function labels will be removed from sight, because they are outside the axis boundary, and `clip=true` (which is the default behaviour). So if you don't want to `enlarge` the limits, you'll need `clip=false`.
3. If you just want an extra grid line, you can add a minor tick, with `minor tick num=1` as in Zarko's answer. If you want a number at each integer, you can set `ytick distance=1`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
     [   
         xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
         xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
         domain=-2:2,
         restrict y to domain=-4:4,
         grid=both,
         clip=true,
         axis lines=middle,
         enlarge y limits={rel=0.1},
         enlarge x limits={rel=0.1},
         ytick distance=1
     ]
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=2] {x}   node [above] {$x$};
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=300] {x^3} node [above] {$x^3$};
     \addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=400] {x^5} node [above] {$x^5$};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
     [
         xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
         xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=-5, ymax=5, % changed
         domain=-2:2,
%         restrict y to domain=-4:4,
         grid=both,
         minor tick num=1,
         clip=true,
         axis lines=middle,
%         enlarge y limits={0.2},
%         enlarge x limits={0.2}
        legend pos=south east,
     ]
     \addplot +[mark=none, thick, smooth] {x}   ;
     \addplot +[mark=none, thick, smooth] {x^3} ;
     \addplot +[mark=none, thick, smooth] {x^5} ;
     \legend{$x$, $x^3$, $x^5$}
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. it is restrict due to `restrict y to domain=-4:4,`
2. labels: do you mind tick labels?
3. you like to have tick label at each unit, i.e.: for y axis at -4,-3, ..., 4?

*edit*: add labels to curves is not so simply, simpler is add legend as is now corrected an above *mwe*.

**addadendum:**
if use of legend is not satisfactory solution, than as complement to  solution of [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t), where is not need to determine end of curves for their labels position ... with help of `intersection` library it can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}
     [
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-2.5, xmax=2.5, ymin=-5, ymax=5, % changed
        domain=-2:2,
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=1,
        axis lines=middle,
        smooth,
        no marks,
        every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
    ]
     \addplot   {x}  node[text=black, right] {$x$};
     \addplot + [name path=A] {x^3};
     \addplot + [name path=B] {x^5};
     %
     \path[name path=C] (0,5) -- (2,5);
     \path[name intersections={of=A and C, by={x3}}] 
            node[below right] at (x3) {$x^3$};
     \path[name intersections={of=B and C, by={x5}}]
            node[below  left] at (x5) {$x^5$};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All right, but how do I put function labels this way? (I am very new to pgfplots, sorry)

Comment: One possibility: `\addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=2] {x}   node [above] {$x$};      \addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=300] {x^3} node [above] {$x^3$};      \addplot [mark=none, thick, samples=400] {x^5} node [above] {$x^5$};` Edit; and keep the `restrict y to domain` and `enlarge y limits` setting.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Gee, thanks, that solved it! Please consider adding your solution as an answer to my question so that I can select it as the best solution :)

Comment: @bertalanp99, i edit my answer, i suggest to use a legend. simpler and elegant ... :-).

Comment: @Zarko I agree, but what use would be a legend in a B&W document? :/

Comment: @bertalanp99, you have a point ... anyway,  meanwhile i add example how to labeled curves as you like to have.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I have seen it. Thank you, you rock :)